# rpm -K reporting MISSING KEYS

Tags: rpm, gnupg

I'm working an a CentOS 5.4 host with rpm version 4.4.2.3-18.el5 and gpg version 1.4-2
I signed an rpm with the command

```
> rpm --define '_signature gpg' --define '_gpg_path /path/to/keys' --define '_gpg_name mygpgname' -K myrpm.rpm
```

The command succeeds, and repeating the command gives a warning message that the rpm was already signed with the key.

However, when I try to verify the signature with an rpm -K it returns a NOT OK (MISSING_KEYS) result.

```
> rpm -K myrpm.rpm

> GNUPGHOME=/path/to/keys rpm --define '_signature gpg' --define '_gnupghome /path/to/keys' --define '_gpg_name mygpgname' -K myrpm.rpm
myrpm.rpm: (SHA1) DSA sha1 md5 (GPG) NOT OK (MISSING KEYS: GPG#12345678)
```

I assume I'm setting the path to the keys wrong somehow.  I've also tried setting GPGPATH=/path/to/keys with no luck.

Does anyone have any suggestions how I can get the rpm -K to find the missing keys ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you imported your public GPG key with the `rpm --import <key>` command?

If you don't want to store your GPG key in your default RPM configuration database(s), then you need to provide a _gpg_path definition in your command.  Note that the last command is missing _gpg_path, although it has nearly every other *gpg** definition that you'll likely need.

Personally, I set such definitions in my $(HOME)/.rpmmacros file to avoid having to type these many times on the command line.

Comment: Yeah, this worked.  First I exported my key, and then did the rpm --import

> GNUPGHOME=/path/to/keys gpg --export -a mygpgname > key.asc
> rpm --import /path/to/keys/key.asc
> rpm -K myrpm.rpm
myrpm.rpm: (sha1) dsa md5 gpg OK